# Parsing JSON formatted Slack payload in Google Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, slack-api

I'm trying to dig deeper into a nested Slack payload to get at some 'fields' I embedded in the original message.

I'm still not even sure this is even JSON.. Slack denies that they even support it.. but I have to process it as JSON?? anyhow maybe someone can illuminate this.

Anyhow.. this is my script to drill into the payload:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var payload = e.parameter.payload;
  var json = JSON.parse(payload);
  var attached = json["original_message"].attachments;
  ...
```

Which the `var attached` is:

```
{
   color=7CD197, callback_id=123, 
   text=Invite *Hello* to this slack?, id=1, 
   fields=[Ljava.lang.Object;@710f54d9, 
   fallback=Something went wrong.. try again, 
   actions=[Ljava.lang.Object;@67e92a25
}
```

to access the `fields` object I would expect to use the following syntax:

```
var field_value = attached.fields[0].value;
```

which I believe should be correct as I want to retrieve the first nested object (there can be more than one) of the `fields` object. The original message fields are as follows:

```
"fields": [
            {
                "title": "Name",
                "value": invitation_name,
                "short": true
            },
            {
                "title": "Email",
                "value": invitation_email,
                "short": true
            }
        ],
```

where `invitation_name` and `invitation_email` are passed values.

So given this logic as above I expect the `var field_value = attached.fields[0].value;` to return the passed value of `invitation_name`.. however I get the following:

`TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.`

The original incoming payload as from `var payload = e.parameter.payload;` does include the `fields` object.. but the `JSON.parse` turns it into `fields=[Ljava.lang.Object;@710f54d9,`..

https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

gives an excellent rundown on how to drill in to a json file and I've used to good effect to get everything I want.. except now I can't dig in any further without generating an `invalid` return..

Comment: Please be more specific what exactly you are trying to do. Is this supposed to be the attachment for a message to an outgoing webhook? (btw that is of course JSON as clearly stated on the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var attachments` is an array so to access `fields[0].value` in it you will need an index.

Try `var field_value = attached[0].fields[0].value;`

Or better:

`var attached = json["original_message"].attachments[0];
 var field_value = attached.fields[0].value;`

Comment: Yeah bro.. that works.. trying to get your head around this is like wrapping your brain around a cut snake..